# To retrieve the frontend ip address of app gateway in azure

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to retrieve the front-end application gateway ip address is there any command to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script below, it works on my side.

In my sample, I configured both `Public` and `Private` Frontend IP configurations.
[image]

```
$AppGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "<Application-gateway-name>" -ResourceGroupName "<Group-name>"
$FrontEndIPs= Get-AzApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
foreach($obj in $FrontEndIPs){
    if($obj.PrivateIPAddress){
        Write-Host "PrivateIPAddress: " $obj.PrivateIPAddress
    }else{
        $resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $obj.PublicIPAddress.Id
        $publicIp = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resource.ResourceGroupName -Name $resource.Name
        Write-Host "PublicIPAddress: " $publicIp.IpAddress
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wang.But like $obj.PrivateIPAddress can we get the public ip address by using property like $obj.PublicIPAddress because it will be more faster and straightforward.

Comment: @S.k No, you can’t. The PublicIPAdress will not be included in the    $obj, it will just be included in the PublicIPAdress resource. So we need to get the PublicIPAdress resource, then get the PublicIPAdress.